# Regular expression for numbers separated by semicolon

Tags: .net, regex

Hi how i can write a regular expression for list of numbers separated with semicolon?

Something like this:

```
1,2,3,5,7,10
```

Size of the list can be long.

Also I need regular expression for decimal numbers only (for example 2.04 (max 6 decimal places) or only in format 2 or some integer number
But no `,` or any other values.

Here is my solution but doesn't work for me in .net validation

```
[0-9]+(\.)[0-9]{0,10}|[0-9]+
```

Comment: Do you need to validate strings like `1,2,3,5,7,10` and `1234.345453`? But not `12.344,32.45554` or `1,3.45,45`? Check [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3a%5b0-9%5d%2b%5c.%5b0-9%5d%7b0%2c6%7d%7c%5b0-9%5d%2b%28%3f%3a%2c%5b0-9%5d%2b%29*%29%5cr%3f%24&i=1%2c2%2c3%2c5%2c7%2c10%0d%0a12.123456%0d%0a12.1234567%0d%0a12.123456%2c12%0d%0a12.12%2c123.2&o=m).

Comment: Ok first expression is for integer numbers separated by column(1,2,3,5,6) like in example. Second expression that is not connect to first one is for decimal numbers

Comment: 1) `^[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)*$` 2) `^[0-9]+\.[0-9]{0,6}$` (maybe `^[0-9]+\.[0-9]{1,6}$` or `^[0-9]*\.[0-9]{1,6}$` will work better). Do not use `\d` in .NET regex (especially for validation), it matches more than `[0-9]`.

Comment: Can you provide example of good and bad inputs and expected matches?

Comment: Wiktor your answer was also correct. Thanks :)

Comment: No, it seems my answer was *the only* correct, as I was using anchors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first expression the following template is suitable:

```
var input = @"The quick 1,2,3 brown fox4,5,6 jumps over the lazy dog";
var pattern = @"([0-9],)+[0-9]";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
//matches: {1,2,3} {4,5,6}
```

You did not specify constraints and possible values in the input line, so I provided a simple template. Thus, for input *"The quick 1,2,3 brown fox4,5,6 jumps over the lazy dog7.0,8.1,9.3"* the result will be *{1,2,3} {4,5,6} {0,8} {1,9}*

Pattern for decimal numbers:

```
var input = @"The quick 1,2,3 brown fox4,5,6 jumps over the lazy dog7.0,8.1,9.3";
var pattern = @"([0-9])+(\.[0-9]{1,6})?";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
// matches: {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6} {7.0} {8.1} {9.3}
```

If you want to allow numbers like *1.* then you can change {1,6} to {0,6}.

There are often decimal numbers in the form .9, in such case you can use `([0-9]+(\.[0-9]{0,6})?)|([0-9]?(\.[0-9]{1,6}))`